# PHP/MySQL - Select RANDOM value from column where another column equals value

Tags: php, mysql, random

I feel like my question is extremely basic and has been answered before but I just can't seem to find anything about it.

Let's say I have a column named 'Names' and another called 'Level'.

```
-----------------------
 Names   |   Level
-----------------------
Scooby   |     3
Daphne   |     1
Shaggy   |     2
Fred     |     3
Velma    |     2
Scrappy  |     0
```

Basically I need a random name from the 'Names' column where 'Level' = 2. In this case randomly Shaggy or Velma. In reality the database will probably be in the dozens if not hundreds of the same 'Level' value.

I've seen code using:

```
SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

And I've tried playing with WHERE in there but with no success. Any ideas? Using PHP to fetch the data from MySQL to return to a Flash file. I apologize for the simplicity of the question.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Names FROM table1
where Level = 2
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/909ca/12)

Comment: @smcjones: your comment makes no sense. This SQL works because that's the way it is written.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT `Names` FROM `table_name`
WHERE `level` = 2
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```